# How to Create screen Form database

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, winforms, ado.net

We are creating a data centric  application,
and want create a Screen (UI) as a Table Structure.

Is any one has good Idea to build the code..?

I was looking the [ironspeed](http://www.ironspeed.com)  abut it is a code generator, i want same functionality at run time, It creates the code for design time..

please show me the good path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was a part of project in which we achieved similar objective by using XUL Render ... we created our own XUL render for this. But, remember our objective was displaying table structure UIs. You can learn more about XUL at [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XUL_Tutorial)

Comment: Yeah!! it's looking something that I was expecting. can u tell me more ..? because I am using C# WPF application and how to do with XUL..?